# Intellij manage tool windows and their shortcuts

Tags: intellij-idea

Intellij provides "Switcher" which not only switches between recent files but also tool windows.

Some tool windows are not being assigned to a shortcut which forces you to open it every time going trough Switcher dialog instead of just doing a simple shortcut.

For example here gradle does not have a shortcut

[image]

Although it is shown as tool window under number 5

[image]

**How do we manage these shortcuts?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Settings -> Keymap -> Other and find Gradle, assign shortcut as you wish (i.e. Alt + 2). It will work. Note that a hint on button (in this example 2:Gradle) will appear after restarting.

Comment: Thanks, i tought i tried this, but i suppose it was not in Other section :)